# Uniqueness of deployment definition in kubernetes namespace

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces

We have multiple environments like dev, qa, prepod etc. We have namespaces based on environment. Right now we name the service with environment as suffix. e.g.,

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: k8s-order-service-develop-deployment
      namespace: dev
      labels:
        k8s-app: k8s-order-service-develop
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          k8s-app: k8s-order-service-develop
```

Instead can I use the following in all namespaces? ie whether `deployment` is unique per namespace?

in dev env:

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: k8s-order-service-deployment
      namespace: dev
      labels:
        k8s-app: k8s-order-service
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          k8s-app: k8s-order-service
```

in qa env:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: k8s-order-service-deployment
      namespace: qa
      labels:
        k8s-app: k8s-order-service
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          k8s-app: k8s-order-service
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the namespace from the deployment definition and name it as deploy.yaml

```
 apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: k8s-order-service-develop-deployment
      labels:
        k8s-app: k8s-order-service-develop
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          k8s-app: k8s-order-service-develop
```

then you can deploy it in a specific namespace using the below command

```
kubectl create -f deploy.yaml -n <namespace-name>

ex: 
kubectl create -f deploy.yaml -n dev
kubectl create -f deploy.yaml -n qa
```

you can look at [kustomize](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize) for more options and felxibility

This way you can use same deployment files for different environments.
and each environment is isolated from the other

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can create same deployments in different namespace. Just be careful when updating deployment in incorrect environment/namespace. Using namespace as a part of shell prompt may be useful.